# In Jquery, many functions with dozens of selectors(from “#A1” to “#A300”). I want to simplify to array through index, each, forEach, var

Tags: jquery, arrays, variables, indexing, each

I have functional code:

```
$(function(){
  $("#A1").click(function(){
  $(".bb").text("apple");
  $(".cc").text("0,1");
  $(".dd").val("0.1");
  });
  })
  
  $(function(){
  $("#A2").click(function(){
  $(".bb").text("fruit");
  $(".cc").text("0,2");
  $(".dd").val("0.2");
  });
  })

  $(function(){
  $("#A3").click(function(){
  $(".bb").text("mango");
  $(".cc").text("0,3");
  $(".dd").val("0.3");
  });
  })
```

Actually I have in my functional code hundreds of events of functions with selectors from "#A1" to "#A300" and I want to simplify to any array through index, each, variables... Please, could anyone help? .dd represents value... all I want is any arrays var X = ["#A1","#A2","#A3"], var y = ["apple","0,1","0.1"], var q = ["fruit","0,2","0.2"] var w = ["mango","0,3","0.3"] with each, index...

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be the following object structure where the main object keys match the ID of the elements and you just add a common class to those elements

```js
const data = {
  A1: { bb: 'apple', cc: '0,1', dd: '0.1'},
  A2: { bb: 'fruit', cc: '0,2', dd: '0.2'},
  A3: { bb: 'mango', cc: '0,3', dd: '0.3'}
}

$(".myClass").click(function() {
  const selectedData = data[this.id];
  $(".bb").text(selectedData.bb);
  $(".cc").text(selectedData.cc);
  $(".dd").val(selectedData.dd);
});
```

```css
li{ display: inline; margin-right:1em; cursor:pointer}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="myClass" id="A1" href="">A1</li>
  <li class="myClass" id="A2" href="">A2</li>
  <li class="myClass" id="A3" href="">A3</li>
</ul>

<div>
  <div>BB : <span class="bb"></span></div>
  <div>CC : <span class="cc"></span></div>
  <div>DD : <input class="dd" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes, functional, thanks Charlie, but is there any way to more simplify through .each() function, like var a = ["#A1", "#A2", "#A3"], var b = ["apple", "0,1", "0.1"], ["fruit", "0,2", "0.2"], ["mango", "0,3", "0.3"] .. or anythink similarly...?